# MATLAB's $\tt filter()$ function for complex valued data

Tags: matlab, filters, complex

I want to use the `filter()` function to implement an FIR filter having complex data values as the input to it. For real, I used this function as `filter(A,1,B`).

**Question :**

Would there be a difference for the corresponding implementation when A and B are in complex domain?

Comment: No difference. It works for both real and complex inputs.

Comment: Even if the Matlab command didn't support complex signals, you could still easily filter a complex signal, since the filter is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @msm said, there's no difference. You can refer to Matlab's documentation here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#inputarg_x which says "Complex Number Support: Yes".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For educational purpose, I wanted to check if numerically calculated values matched with the filter() operation. COuld you please inform me about how I should write out the equation for Moving average model of order / lag 2 for complex valued data? For data in real domain, I was doing $ y(n) = x(n) + h_2 \times x(n-1) + h_3 \times x(n-2)$ where $ n= 1,2,....,50$ data points $x$ is the input source and $h_1 = 1.0, h_2 = 0.6, h_3 = 0.3$ channel coefficients and the operation is multiplication in time domain.

Comment: I was multiplying the channel coefficients with the lagged values of the input. How to write down the equation when values are in complex domain and what is the operator?

Comment: You would still do the same operation - note that you are doing a convolution, and the definition of the convolution operation stays the same as what you described - multiply coefficients with lagged values of the input. Now the coefficients will be complex numbers, and so will the inputs.